# How to attach datepicker to a single dynamic inserted input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked for many years, but after reading so many questions related to this I'm still enable to achieve what I want.

I have a table containing a bunch of input fields Those input fields use the jQuery UI datepicker. There is also a button to add a table row.

When I click the button to add a table row, it is added to the modal correctly. But, the datepicker of all input fire at the same time(no similar id used).

Modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-modal-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="edit-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date" class="col-sm-2 text-left">Date</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="table-responsive">  
                      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                          <tr>  
                            <td><input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Enter date"  class="form-control usedatepicker"/></td>  
                            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                          </tr>  
                      </table>  
                    </div>                     
                  </div>  
              </div>                
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Enter date" class="form-control usedatepicker" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
           $(".usedatepicker").datepicker();    

      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, because the problem with Jquery you can't able to attach the event to dynamic element from Jquery. To overcome this issue, you need to reference the previous available element on DOM as a main selector, like this below code.

```
$('body').on('focus',".class_of_dynamic_element", function(){
$(this).datepicker();});
```

Now the datapicker will attached to that element.

Comment: No, it still does not work. every time I add a new field or try to show the calender on it. there two datepicker which fire at ones